# Performance difference when running same Java code Windows vs Unix

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, unix

I am running below code via eclipse in windows and then in Unix as standalone java.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class readObjectBoeing {



/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ParseException 
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //File file = new File("/opt/app/d1ebp1m1/dv01/Vibhor/test/00017741_repository.dat");
    File file = new File("C:/_Vibhor/00017741_repository.dat");
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] b = toByteArray(is);//read from file;
        Object o1 =null;
        o1 = convertByteArrayToObject(b);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static Object convertByteArrayToObject(byte[] buf) throws Exception 
{

    if (buf.length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    long startTime = -1;
    long step1=-1,step2=-1;
    Object                  obj = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream    bis = null;
    ObjectInputStream       in  = null;
    try 
    {   
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        in  = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        obj = in.readObject();
        step1 = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime ;
        System.out.println("in.readObject()!! :  " + step1);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw e;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (in != null) 
        {
            in.close();
        }
        if (bis != null) 
        {
            bis.close();
        }
        in  = null;
        bis = null;
    }

    return obj;
}
public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream input) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    long count = 0L;
    byte[] buffer =new byte[4096];
    for(int n = 0; -1 != (n = input.read(buffer));){
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return output.toByteArray();
}

}
```

00017741_repository.dat - it is 57Mb file.
In windows `obj = in.readObject();`- it takes me 4-5 seconds.
But in Unix `obj = in.readObject();` it takes me 19 - 25 sec!

I am using VM args -Xmx512m to execute in both cases.

In unix:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
```

In Windows:

```
jre 1.6.0_26
```

What am I missing here? Any suggestions to improve the performance in unix?

Comment: Are your controlling the memory aspects? This is a very memory-intensive operation so any difference in JVM heap settings is going to make a huge difference. BTW obviously not the same JDK, apart from the major version.

Comment: Are the computers have same CPU and memory?

Comment: When you running it from eclipse in windows, your Virtual Machine is already running/in memory (it is used for eclipse). Maybe the JVM need s the the 20 sec to start up. Try to run the program several times (consider caching).

Comment: Yes, I added -Xmx512m in JVM args in both cases.

Comment: @Michael - This is a part of my application code.When my application is running in weblogic, it is taking same 19 sec(at that time JVM is already started)

Comment: And comment out some System.out.println, as native factor of no relevance to the task. Finally it might be the native file system though in this particular case.

Comment: I see that you're calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` at various points in your code. So which part of the code accounts for most of the 19-25 seconds?

Comment: @aix- both the sysout give the same result- it is actually "obj = in.readObject();" that is taking 19 - 25 sec

Comment: @user1373671 - you neglected to answer, what is IMO, an important question: Are the two machines the same hardware? Are you executing the benchmark when they are relatively idle?

Comment: @Arjun - The Unix machine is more powerful than the windows machine.The unix machine is also more idle that windows anytime.Please let me know if you need some specific parameters to judge this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two specific things you can do to figure this one out:

1. make sure that on Unix the file resides on a local file system and not on a network mount;
2. use a profiler (such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp)) to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: The file resides on the local file system.Thanks for the profiler suggestion, will try that out

Comment: obj = in.readObject(); is taking 19 sec in unix and 5 sec in windows.Will a profiler help here?

Comment: @user1373671: I don't think anyone can offer any guarantees at this point, but I think a profiler is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

It is not all together that shocking to find differences like this between platforms. Understand that while the bytecode is the same the JVM is platform specific.

There are a number of areas like this, where you have code that works perfectly on one platform and fails on another. One case I ran into was in drag n drop with files, where unix (at least ubuntu) drops files with a different dataflavor than windows.

You must test on all platforms you intend for your code to run in

Also, in your specific case, you should either try to read from your inputstream more efficiently (using a byte[]) or create a BufferedInputStream to wrap your FileInputStream in

Comment: I am actually getting it directly as byte[] from DB in my actual application. obj = in.readObject(); is taking 19 sec in Unix and 5 sec in windows.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to differ between different JVMs used. For example on *nix systems there are vms like "icedtea" or "OpenJDK" widely used(because they are the default installation).